# Does the Flash Incubator support joystick / gamepad input?

Tags: flash, joystick, joypad

I realize that natively Flash not been able to support joystick / gamepad input in the past and that it can be done using third party software that must be ran separately.  However, with the new Molehill/Stage3D API which supports 3D model integration you would think that joystick / gamepad input would be available.  Does anyone know if this is going to be possible in Flash Player 11 using the Molehill / Stage3D API?

Answer (score 1):

As Thibault Imbert said:

For HID/Joystick, we are still designing some parts of it. We want to make sure it will work on all platforms and generic enough. It will not make FP11, same for ActionScript Workers, which we are still working on.

Thibault
Friday, July 15, 2011 at 3:18 am #

I guess this answers your question. I'm waiting for HID support as well...